# Windows 10 UWP get content dialog to center in screen vertically on mobile

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I am using ContentDialogs throughout my app on Windows 10 Mobile. Both ContentDialog and MessageDialog seem to prefer to anchor to the top of the screen by default. However, I have seen some apps where it shows right in the middle of the screen vertically so it appears as a strip. I cannot figure out how to position it in the middle vertically. I have tried this

```
cd.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
```

Where cd is my ContentDialog intance but this does not work. It is still anchored at the top of the window.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post more of the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should override `Style` for your `ContentDialog`. I've tried to setup `VerticalAlignment.Center` to `Container`, `LayoutRoot` and `BackgroundElement` but it doesn't help. So, place the `BackgroundElement` to center Row in `LayoutRoot` just added new `RowDefinition` and setup `Grid.Row="1"` for your `BackgroundElement`.

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Look at the full ContentDialog Style.

**NOTES**

But be careful, because this works only for mobile. You should apply this style only for mobile platform.

```
<ContentDialog.Style>
    <Style TargetType="ContentDialog">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageTextBaseHighBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumLowBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="{ThemeResource ContentDialogMaxHeight}" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource ContentDialogMinHeight}" />
        <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="{ThemeResource ContentDialogMaxWidth}" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource ContentDialogMinWidth}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentDialog">
                    <Border x:Name="Container">
                        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Border x:Name="BackgroundElement"
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    FlowDirection="{TemplateBinding FlowDirection}"
                                    BorderThickness="{ThemeResource ContentDialogBorderWidth}"
                                    BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush}"
                                    MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding MaxWidth}"
                                    MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxHeight}"
                                    MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}"
                                    MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}" >
                                <Grid x:Name="DialogSpace" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentScrollViewer"
                                        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                        ZoomMode="Disabled"
                                        Margin="{ThemeResource ContentDialogContentScrollViewerMargin}"
                                        IsTabStop="False">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <ContentControl x:Name="Title"
                                            Margin="{ThemeResource ContentDialogTitleMargin}"
                                            Content="{TemplateBinding Title}"
                                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TitleTemplate}"
                                            FontSize="20"
                                            FontFamily="XamlAutoFontFamily"
                                            FontWeight="Normal"
                                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                            IsTabStop="False"
                                            MaxHeight="{ThemeResource ContentDialogTitleMaxHeight}" >
                                                <ContentControl.Template>
                                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                                                        <ContentPresenter
                                                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                        MaxLines="2"
                                                        TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                        ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                </ContentControl.Template>
                                            </ContentControl>
                                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content"
                                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                            FontSize="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"
                                            FontFamily="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"
                                            Margin="{ThemeResource ContentDialogContentMargin}"
                                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                            Grid.Row="1"
                                            TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                    <Grid x:Name="CommandSpace" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Border x:Name="Button1Host"
                                        Margin="{ThemeResource ContentDialogButton1HostMargin}"
                                        MinWidth="{ThemeResource ContentDialogButtonMinWidth}"
                                        MaxWidth="{ThemeResource ContentDialogButtonMaxWidth}"
                                        Height="{ThemeResource ContentDialogButtonHeight}"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                                        <Border x:Name="Button2Host"
                                        Margin="{ThemeResource ContentDialogButton2HostMargin}"
                                        MinWidth="{ThemeResource ContentDialogButtonMinWidth}"
                                        MaxWidth="{ThemeResource ContentDialogButtonMaxWidth}"
                                        Height="{ThemeResource ContentDialogButtonHeight}"
                                        Grid.Column="1"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ContentDialog.Style>
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect. Just one follow up question, you mentioned to do this only in mobile. What is the best way to ensure I only run this code when it is on mobile?

Comment: Look at this article https://mtaulty.com/2015/06/25/m_15864/ 
if you will have some problems - ask new question and community help you